# Tabulate module in Python not giving the desired output

Tags: python, tabulate

I am using tabulate in Python for list:

```py
import tabulate import tabulate
List4 = ['xyz-34t',  'abc-237', 'abc-eq1']
print tabulate(List4)
```

Expected output is

```
xyz-34t
abc-237
abc-eq1
```

Actual output:

```
x y z - 3 4 t
a b c - 2 3 7
a b c - e q 1
```

Comment: try putting an extra set of brackets around List4

Comment: @m02ph3u5 didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the description at https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/ what you want is probably:

```py
import tabulate

list4 = [['xyz-34t'], ['abc-237'], ['abc-eq1']]
print tabulate(list4)
```

---

Replying to your comment: If you mean that above list is the `output of another function` (that you do now have control over) and thus if you're asking how to bring this

```py
['xyz-34t', 'abc-237', 'abc-eq1']
```

to this

```py
[['xyz-34t'], ['abc-237'], ['abc-eq1']]
```

the answer is (using list comprehension):

```py
list = ['xyz-34t', 'abc-237', 'abc-eq1']
list_of_lists = [[x] for x in list]
```

Comment: list I am using as output to some function so how can I convert list in above format ?